# sqlite3 import csv with column and row separator

Tags: csv, sqlite, row, multiple-columns

I'm trying to load in a csv file to a table using sqlite3. (Note I am very new to using sqlite3)

The values in the rows are comma delimited and the rows are separated by new lines.

In my mind using the following in the sqlite3 shell should work:

```
$ sqlite3 features.db

.mode csv

CREATE TABLE csvdata ('A','B','C','D');

.headers off

.separator ROW "\n"
.separator COL ,

.import /home/DATA/testcsv csvdata
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Error: multi-character column separators not allowed for import
```

Perhaps this is because I'm using `"\n"` for the row separator but without a row separator the script will append each comma delimited entry into one long list.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: 
The default conditions to import a csv file to SQLite is:
`,` comma as column separator
`\n` new line for row separator.
So even if you omit both, your code will work.

It's the column separator mentioned in the error.  
Try

```
.separator ","
```

Comment: This seems to be working I think albeit slowly, it's hard to tell though as there are so many lines for the script to read in to the table. I got an error at line 35524987:  INSERT failed: disk I/O error

Comment: Did any rows got inserted?

Comment: Usually `disk I/O error` means problem with the physical storage media and not with the files.

Comment: I'm not sure as it was an error while still running (the process didn't stop at the error). If there was a way to print the lines on the fly as they're inserted into the table I'd be able to check but if it's a disk storage issue then there's not much I can do to fix that

Comment: You can check if the last lines were inserted. If so this means that somewhere in between there was a read/write error.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the disk error problem though as I can load these csv files in using python and they don't overload the RAM and I thought a database was only committed to disk once you use ".save name.db" unless you can specify the db location when initialising it at the start?

Comment: I just checked and it is reading correctly to the table so the original question has been solved by the way so thanks!

Comment: How to change row separator from "\n" to "\r\n"?